# Using promises to get ajax data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have been trying to get the remainder of my code to wait for an ajax call to run before executing as I need info in an array first. I have tried multiple approaches, but I cannot figure out why they won't. It seems like using promises may be best practise in such a situation. Currently the ajax still runs after the .done and final console.log(3).

Please see code below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var selectedChannels = ["ESL_SC2", "OgamingSC2", "cretetion", "freecodecamp", "storbeck", "habathcx", "RobotCaleb", "noobs2ninjas"];
    var numberOfChannels = selectedChannels.length;
    var onlineChannels = [];
    var offlineChannels = [];

function getChannels(){

 for (var count = 0 ; count < numberOfChannels; count++) {

    $.ajax({
    url: "https://wind-bow.hyperdev.space/twitch-api/streams/"+ selectedChannels[count],
    type: "get",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    callback: "?",
      data: {
        }, 
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.stream) {
              var logo = data.stream.channel.logo
              var twitchName = data.stream.channel.display_name
              var details = data.stream.channel.status
              var link = data.stream.channel.url
              onlineChannels.push(twitchName);
              console.log(onlineChannels);
              console.log(1);

              $(".display-area").append("<div class=\"result-box online\"><img src="+ logo +" alt=\"twitchName\" class=\"profile-img\"></img><div class=\"title\">"+ twitchName +"</div><div class=\"description\">"+ details +"</div>");

            } 
        },
    }).done(function(){

    });
 }

 }

/* should run after ajax and onlineChannels array has been populated */
 function completeAjax() {
  var promised = getChannels();
  var promisedComplete = $.when(promised);
  promisedComplete.done(function(){
    console.log(onlineChannels);
    console.log(2);
  });
}

completeAjax();

console.log(3)
});
```

Comment: You are somewhat unclear here, the `done()` method already waits for the ajax call to complete? You have ajax calls in a loop though, did you really mean you want to wait for **all of them** to finish ?

Comment: Hi, yes sorry, I need all of the loops of the ajax for loop to complete before moving onto the code in the completeAjax() function.

Comment: Its now clear what your after.  If you want to execute the completeAjax function after your ajax call is done put it in the complete section.  If you are looping, and executing multiple ajax calls, you need to use the jQuery .done functionality. ( put function the completeAjax funtion in the jQuery done function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can map the ajax calls, and return promises, and then use `$.when.apply` to check that all the ajax calls have completed

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var selectedChannels = ["ESL_SC2", "OgamingSC2", "cretetion", "freecodecamp", "storbeck", "habathcx", "RobotCaleb", "noobs2ninjas"];
    var onlineChannels   = [];
    var offlineChannels  = [];

    function getChannels() {
        return $.map(selectedChannels, function(channel, index) {
            return $.ajax({
                url      : "https://wind-bow.hyperdev.space/twitch-api/streams/" + channel,
                type     : "GET",
                dataType : "jsonp",
                callback : "?",
                data     : {}
            }).done(function(data) {
                if (data.stream) {
                    var logo       = data.stream.channel.logo;
                    var twitchName = data.stream.channel.display_name;
                    var details    = data.stream.channel.status;
                    var link       = data.stream.channel.url;

                    onlineChannels.push(twitchName);

                    $(".display-area").append("<div class=\"result-box online\"><img src=" + logo + " alt=\"twitchName\" class=\"profile-img\"></img><div class=\"title\">" + twitchName + "</div><div class=\"description\">" + details + "</div>");
                }
            });
        });
    }

    $.when.apply($, getChannels()).done(function() {
        // all done, onlineChannels populated
    });

});
```

Comment: indeed, this is a nicer solution then I provided.

Comment: Thank you very much; this does appear to be an elegant solution, I will go read up on some of these methods.

Answer (score 1):

You could use your counter to count down back to zero to see how many Ajax calls still need to finish:

```
for (var count = 0 ; count < numberOfChannels; count++) {
    $.ajax({
        // ...
        success: function(data) {
            count--; // <!--------- decrease count
            // ...
        },
    }).done(function(){
        if (!count) { // <!--------- see if this was the last one finishing.
            // All Ajax done.
            // ...following tasks are initiated here.
            //
        }
    });
}
```

To understand how this works it is important to realise that the `success` and `done` callbacks are not called before your loop has finished, and `count` has reached the maximum. From then on `count` only decreases.